# Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'UIViewContentMode'

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiview, ios7

I am getting a warning in Xcode:

> Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type
>   'UIViewContentMode'

I have a method that I am using to resize an `UIImage` as follows:

```
- (UIImage *)resizedImageWithContentMode:(UIViewContentMode)contentMode
                                  bounds:(CGSize)bounds
                    interpolationQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality {
    CGFloat horizontalRatio = bounds.width / self.size.width;
    CGFloat verticalRatio = bounds.height / self.size.height;
    CGFloat ratio;

    switch (contentMode) {
        case UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill:
            ratio = MAX(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio);
            break;

        case UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit:
            ratio = MIN(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio);
            break;

        default:
            [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"Unsupported content mode: %d", contentMode];
    }
...
```

`UIViewContentMode` seems to reference an Integer so I am not sure on this warning:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIViewContentMode) {
    UIViewContentModeScaleToFill,
    UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,      // contents scaled to fit with fixed aspect. remainder is transparent
    UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill, ...
```

How can I get rid of this warning it seems to be incorrect? Is the `NSLog` in the exception correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the `NSInteger` `UIViewContentMode` to an `int` like this:

```
[NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"Unsupported content mode: %d", (int)contentMode];
```

Comment: Thanks both, I was trying to cast with (NSInteger) before instead.